# How to temporary remove actor in scene2d

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

```
public static void showHs(boolean remove){
    if(remove){
        table.getCell(hsLabel).getActor().setVisible(true);
        table.getCell(hsLabel).getActor().setWidth(labelsWidth);
    }else {
        table.getCell(hsLabel).getActor().setVisible(false);
        table.getCell(hsLabel).getActor().setWidth(0);
    }
}
```

setVisible() doesn't remove actor - it still takes the cell, if I use remove() works, but permanently, can't bring actor at the same place.
Is there any methods like Visibility.GONE ? I searched and ended by being here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void showHs(boolean remove){
    if(remove){
        table.getCell(hsLabel).getActor().setVisible(true);
        table.getCell(hsLabel).getActor().setWidth(labelsWidth);
        table.getCell(hsLabel).expandX();
    }else {
        table.getCell(hsLabel).getActor().setVisible(false);
        table.getCell(hsLabel).getActor().setWidth(0);
        table.getCell(hsLabel).width(0);
    }
}
```

Worked out by setting 0 width to cell, but maybe there is a proper way

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach on how to make your actors inside your table set the visibility. You don't have to set the actor's width to zero to make it "disappear".

The second parameter in **contains** is Identity, If true, == comparison will be used. If false, .equals() comparison will be used.
true if an array contains a value, false if it doesn't.

```
   public static void showHs(boolean visible,Actor yourActor){
        if(table.getChildren().contains(actor,true){
                actor.setVisible(visible);
      }
   }
```